# HAProxy user certificate validation with public CA but unknown domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy

I'm trying to identify my users with public certificates created by official CAs with HAProxy.

I think the problem is that my site domain does not match official CAs domains and client browsers doesn't ask for client user certificate selection to proceed with user validation.

If I try to do the same with my own self signed certificates for identification and a valid ssl certificate for transport there's no problem, but when I try to use government official CAs can't continue and browser shows error SSL_ERROR_RX_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED_ALERT

HAProxy config for certificate validation is quite simple:
This config works:
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/sslcert.pem ca-file /etc/haproxy/selfsigned-cacerts.pem verify required
This config fails:
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/sslcert.pem ca-file /etc/haproxy/official-cacerts.pem verify required

I've tried with different CAs, but only self signed works.
I need some help with HAProxy configuration to show official user client certificate selection to validate email or card id.

Any ideas how to make it work?
Thank you